# ChangeType from string[] to T[] which can be nullable (int..)

Tags: c#, generics, casting, changetype

I've seen a lot of solutions but only for particular cases such as:

- T != int;
- T is to be set by the user e.g. `Method<int>()` or `Method<string>()`...

But I know the type only at runtime, so the above bullet points do not stand. I need to be the most generic possible. Here's the code so far:

```
Type typ = GetTheType(); // the type in which I want to convert those strings. It can be int, double, or whatever
string[] array = GetArrayOfStrings(); // I get the array from somwhere
var arrayConverted = array.Select(p => Convert.ChangeType(p, typ)).ToArray(); // I tested the code with typ=int32 and arrayConverted is of type object[]
```

arrayConverted happens to be of type object[] instead of int[] as I tested it with.
Any idea?

**EDIT:**

The bullet points represent already known solutions, I need a generic one, where I don't know the type untile runtime

Comment: Your second point actually just means that `T` is known at compile-time.

Comment: What other type could it possibly be? You're expecting the compile time type to be an array of a type not known until runtime?  That's impossible.

Comment: @Servy why do you think it's impossible? The type into which I want the items to be cast to is retriven by GetTheType() and it's known only at runtime because I could feed any kind of array...

Comment: @LorenzoG So you think it is possible for the *compile time* type of a variable to be a type that you don't know at compile time, and only know about at runtime?  It's impossible *by definition*.  A type not known at compile time can't be the compile time type of a variable.

Comment: @Servy What I mean is that it could be any of a wide range. It could be int, string, SomeTypeIDefined, etc... Why couldn't it be possibile? could you give me a reference?

Comment: @LorenzoG You need a reference to know that when information is unknown you don't actually know it?  It's true *by definition*.  If you want the compile time type to be the actual type of the object just hard code the type to be the correct type.  You of course can't, because you don't yet know which of the many options it can be.  You can use `object`, because anything you choose can be put into an `object`, but that's the best you can do.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to do what you are asking...

You'll need

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
```

Then this method to do the job.

```
    public T[] ConvertStringArray<T>(string[] data)
    {
        var returnData = (T[])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T),data.Length);
        var i = 0;
        foreach(var item in data)
        {
            returnData[i] = (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFrom(item);
            i++;
        }
        return returnData;
    }
```

Just to point out - if one or more of the strings passed in the array are not convertable to type T, this will throw a conversion exception.

Comment: this would be ok if I knew the T before compiling, isn't it?

Comment: @LorenzoG Yes, which is what you indicated with this "•T is to be set by the user e.g. Method<int>() or Method<string>()...".

Comment: If you do not know the type needed at compile time, you'll have to rely on reflection (you can create an instance of a type from an assembly with only a string containing the type name). Keep in mind there is significant overhead to these kinds of reflection calls and if you have a lot of strings in your array it could have negative performance impact. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx.

Comment: Sorry the Activator class in not in the Reflection namespace, it is in the System namespace.

Comment: I modified the question so it should be more clear. I'm using reflection to get the type, in fact GetTheType() does exactly so. How should I proceed from there?